# How can I overlay a video ontop of background image?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a command which creates waves ontop of a background image:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "Assets/Screens/new.png" -i "Temp/video.mp4" -i "Temp/audio.mp3" -filter_complex "[2:a]showwaves=mode=cline:s=255x81:scale=sqrt:colors=0x222222,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[w];[v][w]overlay=240:594,scale=1920:1080[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 2:a -movflags +faststart -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -preset veryfast -shortest "output.mp4"
```

How can I also overlay a 1024x576px video at position 756:252?

I have already included the video file as the second (1:v) input, but I can't seem to get the filters to play nicely.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Overlay the image with the video, and feed the overlay-ed output to your existing filter.

The part `[1:v][0:v]overlay=756:252[t]` overlays `video.mp4` and `new.png` into intermediate video stream `[t]`.

`[t][w]overlay=240:594` replaces your `[v][w]overlay=240:594`.

Complete command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "Assets/Screens/new.png" -i "Temp/video.mp4" -i "Temp/audio.mp3" -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]overlay=756:252[t];[2:a]showwaves=mode=cline:s=255x81:scale=sqrt:colors=0x222222,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[w];[t][w]overlay=240:594,scale=1920:1080[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 2:a -movflags +faststart -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -preset veryfast -shortest "output.mp4"
```

I hope I got it right, testing is difficult without having the inputs...

Comment: Thank you, after a bit of tinkering this helped a lot :)